CreatePublicKeyCredentialRequest throws PhenotypeContext.setContext()
Does anybody know why the following function throws this error on some devices and how I could fix it
"Error: Must call PhenotypeContext.setContext() first w type: android.credentials.CreateCredentialException.TYPE_UNKNOWN w obj: androidx.credentials.exceptions.CreateCredentialUnknownException: Must call PhenotypeContext.setContext() first"
suspend fun registerPasskey( jsonString: String): CreatePublicKeyCredentialResponse {
        val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(activity)

        
        val json = JSONObject(jsonString)

       
        val rpName = json.getJSONObject("rp").getString("name")
        val rpId = json.getJSONObject("rp").getString("id")

        val userVerification = json.getJSONObject("authenticatorSelection").getString("userVerification")
        val requireResidentKey = json.getJSONObject("authenticatorSelection").getBoolean("requireResidentKey")
        val residentKey = json.getJSONObject("authenticatorSelection").getString("residentKey")
        val authenticatorAttachment = json.getJSONObject("authenticatorSelection").getString("authenticatorAttachment")

        val userId = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("id")
        val userName = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("name")
        val userDisplayName = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("displayName")

        val pubKeyCredParams = json.getJSONArray("pubKeyCredParams")

        val attestation = json.getString("attestation")
        val timeout = json.getLong("timeout")
        val challenge = json.getString("challenge")

        val excludeCredentials = json.getJSONArray("excludeCredentials")

        
        val request = CreatePublicKeyCredentialRequest(
            requestJson = JSONObject().apply {
                put("rp", JSONObject().apply {
                    put("name", rpName)
                    put("id", rpId)
                })
                put("user", JSONObject().apply {
                    put("id", userId)
                    put("name", userName)
                    put("displayName", userDisplayName)
                })
                put("challenge", challenge)
                put("pubKeyCredParams", pubKeyCredParams)
                put("timeout", timeout)
                put("excludeCredentials", excludeCredentials)
                put("authenticatorSelection", JSONObject().apply {
                    put("authenticatorAttachment", authenticatorAttachment)
                    put("requireResidentKey", requireResidentKey)
                    put("residentKey", residentKey)
                    put("userVerification", userVerification)
                })
                put("attestation", attestation)
            }.toString()
        )

    
        return credentialManager.createCredential(activity, request) as CreatePublicKeyCredentialResponse
    }

